# usage of hashtable and map

Tags: c++

The hashtable and map is hashtable is implemented as a hash function but map is implemented as a tree.

My question is, in what situation, hashtable can not be used but a map is a must?

Comment: Potential duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196995/is-there-any-advantage-of-using-map-over-unordered-map-in-case-of-trivial-keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One motivation for choosing to use a map over a hashtable is the constraints which each one places on the key type used in the template instantiation.  As described in [the documentation for hash_map in the SGI implementation of STL](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/hash_map.html), an instantiation hash_map requires provision of a functor which hashes K.  The STL includes a functor, [std::hash](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/hash.html), which does this, but it is only implemented for a limited set of types T.

Instantiation of std::map on the other hand only requires a functor which compares objects of type K to generate a weak ordering.  The standard functor [std::less](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/less.html) will work for any T which defines an operator<.

This means that, for many user-defined types, adding the support necessary to use the type as a key in a std::map is much less than that required to use it in a std::hash_map.

Aside from the question of overhead,

1. Only std::map, not std::hash_map, guarantees that the keys will be ordered, so if this is a requirement, use std::map
2. hash_map is not part of the standard, so while some STL implementations include it, this is not true of all implementations.  Using hash_map therefore has potential impact on the portability of your program.

Comment: hash_map will be included in C++0x as std::unordered_map

Comment: @gareth - std::unordered_map is already widely available (GCC/VS08) as part of TR1. Also, generating hash keys for custom types is trivial with the Boost.Hash library, which should be standardized someday (maybe in TR2?)

Answer (score 5):

There are a number of potential reasons.

- When it is not possible or at least not practical to provide a sensible hashing function for your keys.
- When the ordering specified by `std::map` is necessary or desirable.
- When you only have access to the standard library and are limited as to what other libraries you can use.

Answer (score 2):

The *runtime characteristics* are different:

A **tree-based map** always has a runtime (worst case, average case) in the order of O(log *n*), i.e. the height of the (balanced) binary search tree.

**Hash maps**, on the other hand, have a much more complicated runtime behaviour. But in the usual case, a hash table has an *expected* runtime of O(1), i.e. *constant* overhead.

In general, the *worst case* is O(*n*), which sounds bad. However, it can be shown that for a good choice of parameters, this worst case gets so rare as to not play a role in practice. “Rare” here means *really* rare, as in winning the lottery ten times in a row and then being killed by a comet. In practice, a bad choice of parameters (hashing technique, load factor …) can raise this probability considerably.

Answer (score 1):

When you depends on that the keys are sorted.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer with regard to std::[unordered_map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unordered_map_(C%2B%2B)) (hashtable) and std::[map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Std::map) (tree).  Note that neither of these actually specify implementation mechanisms.  Basically, you use map when you need to access the keys in sorted order, and unordered_map otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to find the 'next' item in the data structure, a hashtable cannot be used because it doesn't keep items in a traversable order.