# mapping 1D array with two points

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to store random snapshots of a a 1D array `arr` using a mapping of 2 points say `a,b` to utilise in a dynamic program. like say

```
P1 => (4,5)   = [1,1,0,2,1]
P2 => (10,13) = [5,6,3,4,3]
P3 => (15,23) = [11,13,9,12,14]
```

so on.....
Later I need to add them to array `A` having also n elements like arr.
like say `A = [1,1,1,1,1]`

so now after `P1` i have `A` as : `[2,2,1,3,2]` and so on till P ends.
I am not sure how to map these points `P1,P2 ...`  with the array `arr` and then later sum it with array A.
I tried using a 3D array to store those points and then the array.But it seems bulky and not utilised in an efficient way.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a

```
std::map<std::pair<int, int>, std::vector<int>> m;
```

then you can use it as `m[{10, 20}].push_back(42);`.

The data in the question for example could be stored with

```
m[{4, 5}] = {1, 1, 0, 2, 1};
m[{10, 13}] = {5, 6, 3, 4, 3};
m[{15, 23}] = {11, 13, 9, 12, 14};
```

Comment: can I store all of them at once, like `m[std::make_pair(10, 20)]= [1,2,3,4,5]`

Answer (score 0):

According to this answer posted by GManNickG https://stackoverflow.com/a/2197015/7943474, un unordered_map will use more memory but in your case it can be much faster since you are not going to add/delete points once you initialize your set of data.

In this case you should consider:

```
#include <unordered_map>

std::unordered_map<std::pair<int, int>, std::vector<int>> uMap;
```

and then insert your element as:

```
std::pair<int, int> point(4, 5);
std::vector<int> arr;
arr.push_back(1);
arr.push_back(1);
and so on..

uMap.insert(point, arr);
```

To find and element in the uMap, you can use the find() method:

```
std::unordered_map<std::pair<int, int>, std::vector<int>>::const_iterator it = uMap.find(point);
```

and then update data with

```
it->second[0] + A[0];
it->second[1] + A[1];
and so on..
```

For more reference see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/