# Unordered_map or hashMap existing hash function modify?

Tags: c++, stl, hashmap, unordered-map

I used ***unordered_map<long long int, long long int>*** ***the key may take values of upto 1e9***, this lead to my answer being Time Limit Exceeded.

when I used map<long long int, long long int> it was succesful.

I came to know from  other answers that ***unordered_map is bad when hash function is bad , is there a way to change the hash function of this unordered_map*?**

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016175/c-unordered-map-using-a-custom-class-type-as-the-key

Comment: It seems very unlikely that the standard hash function for `long long int` would be bad, and even more unlikely that `map` would be better. I think your problems are probably caused by some other issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are free to do so.

The third template parameter of `std::unordered_map` is the hash function going to be used, and it should be a functor that satisfy the requirement listed [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Hash).

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map Also check here, google or follow the link for anything you don't understand and it should not be too hard to follow.

Answer (score 1):

I think there might be another cause to this.

If there are more **insertions and deletions** as compared to **lookups**, then `map` is faster. However, if there are more **lookups**, then `unordered_map` should provide a performance boost.

Have a look at this:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196995/is-there-any-advantage-of-using-map-over-unordered-map-in-case-of-trivial-keys#:~:text=map%20just%20has%20a%20few,it%20lacks%20the%20large%20array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196995/is-there-any-advantage-of-using-map-over-unordered-map-in-case-of-trivial-keys#:%7E:text=map%20just%20has%20a%20few,it%20lacks%20the%20large%20array).

PS: Could you share the question once, for a greater insight?

Comment: *"If there are more insertions and deletions as compared to lookups, then map is faster. However, if there are more lookups, then unordered_map should provide a performance boost."* - that's awfully presumptuous; a lot will depend on collision proneness of keys, hash function used, hash table size (e.g. GCC tends to use prime sizes, Visual C++ powers of 2), CPU/memory/cache architectural properties, number of values stored....  See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/3999891/410767 for hard stats contradicting that.