# maps and unordered_maps time complexity analysis

Tags: c++, dictionary, maps, time-complexity, c++14

I used to believe that unordered_map is better in time-complexity than map in C++. But today while I was doing a problem(Molly's Chemicals), I got time-limit exceeded. After a lot of guess-work(because I thought my solution was correct), I tried using a map instead of an unordered_map and as a surprise I got it accepted.In some cases in which due to a lot of collisions unordered_map can have a big constant multiplier which will increase its actual complexity to greater than that of a map(corrections are welcomed).

i searched a lot about `time complexity` of different `functions of maps and unordered maps` but i didnt find a proper content as i want to know that when should i use maps or unordered maps. Can anybody please explain  difference between the use of maps and unoredered_maps in terms of time complexity.

Comment: `ordered maps` keep keys in a sorted manner (as the name suggests). Time complexity for these depends on where they are used (how frequent **inserts** are, how frequent **lookups** are, etc.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any advantage of using map over unordered\_map in case of trivial keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196995/is-there-any-advantage-of-using-map-over-unordered-map-in-case-of-trivial-keys)

Comment: thanks for suggesting me @ghost. but i want to know the difference between the use of maps and unoredered maps in terms of time complexity . In simple terms ,  please tell me the insertion , seraching , finding in maps time complexity

Comment: I did get TLE in the same problem since too many elements in the same bucket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### unordered_map

Requirements of `unordered_map` in ISO C++, [[tab:container.hash.req]](http://eel.is/c++draft/unord.req#tab:container.hash.req):

> ```
> +------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
> |    Expression    |                     Complexity                      |
> +------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
> | a_­uniq.insert(t) | Average case O(1), worst case O(a_uniq.size()).     |
> | a.erase(k)       | Average case O(a.count(k)), worst case O(a.size()). |
> | b.find(k)        | Average case O(1), worst case O(b.size()).          |
> +------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
> ```

The time complexity of each operator in `unordered_map` in the worst case is `O(n)`. It will happen if all elements in the same [`bucket`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/bucket).

And a special test data may be constructed by tracing the code of compiler like [the post](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/62393) on Codeforces shows how to construct such test data on gcc.

### map

Requirements of `map` in ISO C++, [[tab:container.assoc.req]](http://eel.is/c++draft/associative.reqmts#tab:container.assoc.req):

> ```
> +------------------+--------------------------+
> |     Expression   |        Complexity        |
> +------------------+--------------------------+
> | a_­uniq.​insert(​t) | logarithmic              |
> | a.erase(k)       | log(a.size())+a.count(k) |
> | b.find(k)        | logarithmic              |
> +------------------+--------------------------+
> ```

The time complexity of `map` is guaranteed to be `O(log n)`.

Answer (score 0):

The data structure behind map is rb-tree while unordered_map uses hash table as its data structure. So we can analayze these two containers via anaylayzing rb-tree and hash table.

find/insert an element in map: O(log n)
find/insert an element in unordered_map: O(1)