# std::mutiset vs std::vector to read and write sorted strings to a file

Tags: c++, stl

I've a file say `somefile.txt` it contains names (single word) in sorted order.

I want to updated this file, after adding new name, in sorted order.

Which of the following will be most preferred way and why ?

**Using a `std::multiset`**

```
std::multiset<std::string> s;

std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(fin),//fin- object of std::fstream
          std::istream_iterator<std::string>(), 
          std::inserter(s, s.begin())); 

s.insert("new_name");

//Write s to the file
```

*OR*

**Using a `std::vector`**

```
std::vector<std::string> v;

std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(fin),
              std::istream_iterator<std::string>(), 
              std::back_inserter(v));

v.push_back("new_name");

std::sort(v.begin(),v.end());

//Write v to the file.
```

Comment: Note: You should use the range constructor instead of copy. (Though given that these are only input iterators the difference will be small)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The multiset is slower to insert objects than the vector, but they are held sorted.
The multiset is likely to take up more memory than the vector as it has to hold pointers to an internal tree structure.  This may not always be the case as the vector may have some empty space.

I guess if you need the information to grow incrementally but always to be ready for immediate access in order then the multi set wins.

If you collect the data all at once without needing to access it in order, it is probably simpler to push it onto the vector and then sort.  So how dynamic is the data to be stored is the real criterion.

Answer (score 2):

```
std::string new_name = "new_name";
bool inserted = false;
std::string current;
while (std::cin >> current) {
    if (!inserted && new_name < current) {
        std::cout << new_name << '\n';
        inserted = true;
    }
    std::cout << current << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Both options are basically equivalent.

In a performance-critical scenario, the `vector` approach will be faster, but your perf is largely going to be constrained by the disk in this case; which container you choose won't matter much.

Comment: Yes. set container are said to have faster insertions and removals except at the end, but that is not always true either I've heard. I think by the master himself. It has to do with the compactness in memory of vector.

Answer (score 0):

Vectors are faster from what I could see from this guy's testing  (http://fallabs.com/blog/promenade.cgi?id=34). I would suggest that you test it out and see for yourself. Performance is often related to platform and especially, in this case, datasets.

From his testing, he concluded that simple element works best with vector. For complex element (more than 4 strings for instance), multiset is faster.

Also, since vectors are big arrays, if you're adding lots of data, it may be worth looking into using another type of container (linked list for instance or a specialized boost container see [Is there a sorted_vector class, which supports insert() etc.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710221/is-there-a-sorted-vector-class-which-supports-insert-etc)).