# C++ unordered_set of vectors

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

Can I create a unordered_set of vectors in C++? something like this

```
std::unordered_set<std::vector<int>> s1;
```

because I know that is possible with the "set" class of the std lib but seems that it doesn't work for the unordered version
thanks

Update:
this is the exactly code that I'm trying to use

```
typedef int CustomerId;
typedef std::vector<CustomerId> Route;
typedef std::unordered_set<Route> Plan;

// ... in the main
Route r1 = { 4, 5, 2, 10 };
Route r2 = { 1, 3, 8 , 6 };
Route r3 = { 9, 7 };
Plan p = { r1, r2 };
```

and it's all right if I use set, but I receive a compilation error when try to use the unordered version

```
main.cpp:46:11: error: non-aggregate type 'Route' (aka 'vector<CustomerId>') cannot be initialized with an initializer list
    Route r3 = { 9, 7 };
```

Comment: Did you mean something like [`std::unordered_set<std::vector<int>>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) actually?

Comment: I'm sorry, I have digit the incorrect class name, I mean exactly unordered_set

Comment: *How* doesn't it work? What's the problem you're having?

Comment: What does *doesn't work* mean? Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Yes you can have an `std::unordered_set<std::vector<some_type>>`

Comment: I've updated the post to clarify the error

Comment: @CattaniSimone Uh... what please? What compiler are you using that `r3` fails but not the `Plan` constructor?

Comment: @Barry - happens with me too when using clang.

Answer (score 56):

Sure you can. You'll have to come up with a hash though, since the default one (`std::hash<std::vector<int>>`) will not be implemented. For example, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2595226/2069064), we can build:

```
struct VectorHash {
    size_t operator()(const std::vector<int>& v) const {
        std::hash<int> hasher;
        size_t seed = 0;
        for (int i : v) {
            seed ^= hasher(i) + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed<<6) + (seed>>2);
        }
        return seed;
    }
};
```

And then:

```
using MySet = std::unordered_set<std::vector<int>, VectorHash>;
```

You could also, if you so choose, instead add a specialization to `std::hash<T>` for this type (**note** this *could* be undefined behavior with `std::vector<int>`, but is definitely okay with a user-defined type):

```
namespace std {
    template <>
    struct hash<std::vector<int>> {
        size_t operator()(const vector<int>& v) const {
            // same thing
        }
    };
}

using MySet = std::unordered_set<std::vector<int>>;
```

Comment: The second half is probably UB. As far as the library is concerned, I don't think `std::vector<int>` counts as a user-defined type.

Comment: Why is the default one (`std::hash<std::vector<int>>`) not used?

Comment: @Divyansh There is no `std::hash<std::vector<int>>` - it's not provided by the standard library.

Comment: How does std::set<vector<int>> work then if there is no default hash?

Comment: @NanoNi `std::set` isn't a hash table, it's a binary tree. It uses `<`

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to a custom-written hasher, Boost provides a hasher for many standard library types. This should work in your case:

```
#include <boost/container_hash/hash.hpp>

std::unordered_set<
  std::vector<int>,
  boost::hash<std::vector<int>>
> s1;
```

Reference: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/hash/reference.html

In older Boost versions, the header file was `boost/functional/hash.hpp`.