# How to remove duplicates of type vector<string> in C++?

Tags: c++, vector, unordered-set

I know that a good way to prevent duplicates is to use an `unordered_set`. However, this method does not seem to work when I want to have an `unordered_set<vector<string>>`. How can I go about doing this? For example, I want to prevent `<"a", "b", "c">` from being duplicated in my `unordered_set<vector<string>>`.

Can this `unordered_set<vector<string>>` be used outside the defined class as well?

Code:

```
unordered_set<vector<string>> abc({"apple", "ball", "carrot"});
abc.insert({"apple", "ball", "carrot"});

cout << abc.size() << endl;     //abc.size() should be 1
```

Comment: I think i must define a hash myself? No idea how to do it though

Comment: Can you post a very minimal example which adds {"a", "b", "c"} twice, and checks the set's size()?

Comment: It does not compile because no hash is defined for `unordered_set<vector<string>>`

Comment: How about simply using std::set?

Comment: `unordered_set<vector<string>, my_hash_class>` Tried this?

Comment: Might be a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29855908/10077

Comment: @Erik Alapäa he doesn't even need to define his own comparison operator (unless lexicographical comparison is insufficient for his use case)

Comment: @Erik vector already has the required  comparison operator

Comment: @James Tan, maybe you could get an answer instead of lot of comments if you paste your current non-working code...

Comment: @JamesTan -- You didn't mention exactly what is the error.  Compilation, runtime, etc.?

Comment: I got a similar error saying "The C++ Standard doesn't provide a hash for this type."  Seems pretty clear. Look up the template parameters to see how to add a hasher. I'd just concatonate all the strings with a rarely used character as the connector. It won't know the difference between {"a+b+c"} and {"a", "b", "c"} if the connector is '+' but maybe you know that '\0' is not used in any of the strings? (although xyz seems likely)

Comment: @NeilButterworth true, I remove my comment.

Comment: This may help  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016175/c-unordered-map-using-a-custom-class-type-as-the-key

Comment: @KennyOstrom I thought about concatenating as well, but I need them to be separated eventually, so there would be additional overhead to split the concatenated string back to the vector

Comment: No, that was just in the hasher, not the data itself, but nevermind anything I said ... go to the link that has the actual working implementation.

Comment: Another way would be using std::sort and then std::unique

Answer (score 0):

There is a number of ways to get rid of duplicates, building a set out of your objects is one of them. Whether it is going to be `std::set` or `std::unordered_set` is up to you to decide, and the decision usually depends on how good of a hash fuction can you come up with.

This in turn requires the knowledge of the domain, e.g. what your vectors of strings represent and what values can they have. if you do come up with a good hash, you can implement it like this:

```
struct MyHash
{
    std::size_t operator()(std::vector<std::string> const& v) const 
    {
        // your hash code here
        return 0; // return your hash value instead of 0
    }
};
```

Then you just declare your `unordered_set` with that hash:

```
std::unordered_set<std::vector<std::string>, MyHash> abc;
```

I would say it's a safe bet to just go with a `std::set` at first though, unless you have a good hash function on your mind.