# How this hasher works?

Tags: c++, vector, hash

I'm trying to understand how [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29855908/c-unordered-set-of-vectors) beauty works, can someone give me some clues?

```
struct VectorHash {
    size_t operator()(const std::vector<int>& v) const {
        std::hash<int> hasher;
        size_t seed = 0;
        for (int i : v) {
            seed ^= hasher(i) + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed<<6) + (seed>>2);
        }
        return seed;
    }
};
```

Used as:

```
using MySet = std::unordered_set<std::vector<int>, VectorHash>;
```

Why it use this number?

```
0x9e3779b9 = 10011110001101110111100110111001
```

Why it add the `seed` shifted `6` to the left and `2` to the rigth?

Why the use of Bitwise Exclusive OR assignment `^=`?

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948780/magic-number-in-boosthash-combine).

Comment: this is the implementation used by [`boost::hash_combine`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/hash/reference.html#boost.hash_combine), which is explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35985960/c-why-is-boosthash-combine-the-best-way-to-combine-hash-values

Comment: Thanks for the references, solved!