# std::vector as key in std::set and std::unordered_set

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, vector, stl

I'm writing a program that evaluates tons of positions in a board game (i.e. othello). My board representation is an `std::vector`. Since the same position can occure more times in processing, I use an `std::set<std::vector>` to store examined positions.

In term of performances I don't know if it is preferable to use `std::set` (that works *natively* because `std::vector` implements all the operators required) or `std::unordered_set` with a good *hashing* function (i.e. `boost::hash_range(...)`).

In alternative are there other good solutions to achieve the same goal? (Maybe different board representations [bitboards for sure when available] or different data structures?)

EDIT ************************************** EDIT

This is the pseudo code to fetch boards:

```
enqueue initial board
while queue not empty:
    dequeue a board
    if board is already examined: //std::set search
        continue
    put board in examined boards
    if board is solved:
        print solution
    else:
        for each possible board that can arise out of this one:
            add board to end of queue
```

Comment: Why not a vector of vectors?

Comment: If you are talking about performance, you need to measure what is fast for your problem. And `std::vector` always should be the candidate to compare with if possible.

Comment: @NathanOliver with a vector checking if is a position is already examined requires O(n). With set O(logn) and with unsorted_set O(1). When n is extremly big vector is a bottleneck

Comment: I think you need a little more explanation/example in your question then as I am unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @NathanOliver I improved the question with the pseudo code :)

Comment: First I'd create something that works, and only after this I'd check if optimization is needed.

Comment: @kuket15 If you want performance, then profile. Asking questions before profiling is useless. Also, your reliance on O(whatever) notation is obsolete since 1980th, or at least it requires real-world verification. In 2015 we are living in the world of optimizing compilers, cache hierarchies, branch predictors, out-of-order execution etc. Naive theoretical reasoning about what your code algorithmic complexity is just doesn't work anymore. P.S. Use `vector` by default.

Comment: @Drop As many suggest I'll benchmark all different conditions. Obviously it's the best thing to do. But I really doubt `vector` is even comparable with `set` for my purposes. Anyway i think *Try it yourself* is the best answer to my post.

Comment: I don't think I would recommend using `vector<vector<...>>` here - the original poster seems to want uniqueness, after all.

Answer (score 1):

see

[Why on earth would anyone use set instead of unordered_set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349734/why-on-earth-would-anyone-use-set-instead-of-unordered-set)

[what is the difference between set and unordered_set in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16075890/what-is-the-difference-between-set-and-unordered-set-in-c)

Basically: unless you're concerned about the order of the values you should probably go with unordered_set.

But as for all other performance problems: When in doubt --> start measuring.
Implement both "less" and "hash", then try it with both classes and check which is performing better (Note: in this case you don't have almost the same API anyway. So it shouldn't take you long to switch classes for a test)

Comment: @celticminstrel yeah, it is. no reasons to define it again