# Difference between set and unordered set C++

Tags: c++, stl, set, unordered-set

Why does this work?

```
set <pair<int, int>> prevIslands;
```

While this does not:

```
unordered_set <pair<int, int>> prevIslands;
```

And gives the error:

```
required from 'struct std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<std::hash<std::pair<int, int> > >, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<std::pair<int, int>, std::hash<std::pair<int, int> > > >'
```

Do set and unordered_set have different requirements from the underlying container object?

Comment: `unordered_set` requires that there is a hash function for the item type. As I recall g++ and MSVC used to differ in what types their standard library implementations provided hashing for, with g++ deficient in its support for `enum` types. I'm not sure what precisely the standard requires, but you can just write a hashing function for any type you want to use.

Comment: A simple hash for a tuple is to xor together the hashes for the individual tuple components.

Comment: [You need to supply the additional template arguments](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) to  `unordered_set` for your code to compile.

Comment: For a better understanding, see the differences between them: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16075890/what-is-the-difference-between-set-and-unordered-set-in-c